# Side by side DIV not aligning

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a couple DIVs that will sit side by side each taking up half of the width of the div that holds them.  Getting the side-by-side with float: left is working properly, but my elements don't line up properly.  I made a jsfiddle to show you what I mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/kzFqU/

As you can see, it looks alright, but if you make the results square really wide the right alignment of the inputs goes to crap.

```
<div class="container-narrow">
<div class="form_field">
    <label>Full Width</label>
    <input type="text" name="what">
</div>
<div class="form_field halfwidth">
    <label>Half Width</label>
    <input type="text" name="what">
</div>
<div class="form_field halfwidth">
    <label>Also Half Width</label>
    <input type="text" name="what">
</div>
<div class="form_field">
    <label>Full Width</label>
    <input type="text" name="what">
</div>
```

and the css

```
body {
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
background:whitesmoke;
}

.container-narrow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
}

.form_field {
    padding: 10px;
}

.form_field input {
    width:100%;
}

.form_field label {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.form_field input {
    clear:both;
}

.halfwidth {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following just after your second half-width div:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the floats after the halfwidth elements such as:

```
.form_field:before,
.halfwidth:before {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: "\0020";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The above solution is some self-clearing goodness that solves the issue! See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kzFqU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the padding applied by `.form_field`. I think this will achieve the effect you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/cx8T2/

```
.halfwidth {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

...

<div class="halfwidth">
    <div class="form_field">
        <label>Half Width</label>
        <input type="text" name="what">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="halfwidth">
    <div class="form_field">
        <label>Also Half Width</label>
        <input type="text" name="what">
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) property from CSS3 will also work without requiring you to change your markup at all, but it's not supported by older browsers:

```
.halfwidth {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```